# Grails and HTML area

Tags: html, grails

I want to update g:remoteField it self by a searching code, with some other fields. It is working but, in every key I type it call action and the cursor goes invisible. How to make it always focused to editable mode.

Here is my code

```
<g:remoteField id="name" 
               name="name" 
               action="itemSearch" 
               update="nameDiv" 
               optionKey="id" 
               value="${flash.itm}" 
               placeholder="Name"
/>
```

autofocus is not working.